# Mongoose update not updating document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update documents in my MongoDB via Mongoose but for some reason the requested documents can not be found...

```
Call.update({_id: data.call._id}, { $set: { approved: value }}, function (error, response) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
    if (error) {
        callback(error, null);
    } else {
        callback(null, response);
    }
});
```

`data.call._id` contains a valid document `_id` and `approved` is of type `Number`.

`response` outputs the following:

```
{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0, lastOp: { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 0, high_: 0 }, electionId: 56a92375bfb5c1abc4e825a7 }
```

The document is never updated in the database... `value` will either be set to `1` or `-1` depending on an earlier condition.

Model:

```
const callSchema = new Schema({
    start: Date,
    duration: String,
    callerNumber: String,
    callerNumberAreaCode: String,
    trackingNumber: String,
    destinationNumber: String,
    answered: String,
    customerId: String,
    approved: Number
}, { collection: 'calls'});

const Call = mongoose.model('Call', callSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this could help someone.

Make sure that your Scheme had a FIELD totally correct with your FIELD in `$set` clause.

For example:

if your updating is (set `address` field):

```
User.update({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("<doc_id>")}, { $set: { address: "New York" }}, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err:", err)
    } else {
        console.log("success with response:", res)
    }
})
```

Your scheme needs to contain `address` field, such as:

```
let User = new mongoose.Scheme({
    name: String,
    address: String
})
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.. I've been pulling my hair on this one.

Answer (score 0):

In [Model.update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) you don't need to use `$set`. Try this:

```
Call.update({_id: data.call._id}, { approved: value }, function (error, response) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
    if (error) {
        callback(error, null);
    } else {
        callback(null, response);
    }
});
```

Comment: There is an issue with actually finding the document in the database. I've just replaced this with a `findOne()` method and the response of this function is empty, even though the document trying to be found exists in the db.

Comment: Try this with `findOne(_id: ObjectId(data.call._id))`, and `const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
`

Comment: `null` is still being returned

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused right now. Without the underscore? `id: ObjectId(data.call._id)`

Comment: I've just tried running findOne() with a hardcoded ID and I'm still getting null, I've added my model to the original post... As far as I'm aware everything's okay?

Comment: @leaksterrr Yes, it's absolutely good. I don't know what is the problem. :/

Comment: Seems to be an issue with Mongoose. I've managed to update documents perfectly fine using the MongoDB client